# TcxDBTreeList Delphi 7 not arrowing down

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7, treelist

I am using the TcxDBTreeList component with Delphi 7 and I am having some wierd results adding rows.

I am using a Tclientdataset for my data. I am appending to it and the row shows up correctly in the treelist.

However, its never allowing me to arrow down past the 2nd node in the tree,  Even if I've added 10 more nodes.

I'm sure it's got to be something simple.  A setting or what not.

Can someone tell me what I'm not doing or doing incorrectly?

Thanks,

David

Comment: you need to include the code you're using, in this way will be much easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make certain that new rows added to the ClientDataSet has unique KeyField values.  If this is the case, everything should work correctly.